# python requests not able to get the bearer token

Tags: python, python-requests, header

I'm not able to get the request header from this API:
How to get the bearer token dynamically, seems that requests lib is returning only the **response header**, but I need the **request header** with the bearer.

```
url_site = 'https://www.rappi.com.br/lojas/900520986-makro-atacadista-nc/mercearia'

url_api = 'https://services.rappi.com.br/api/ms/web-proxy/dynamic-list/cpgs/'
    
    with requests.session() as r:
        print(r.get(url_api).headers)
```

[image: Bearer token needed]

Expected output:
Get the bearer token and pass it for the headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Curl format I copy this request from browser that you can implement in request obviously but is not the question. This API return a json that contains your bearer, so just send in a header into requests normaly.

```
curl 'https://services.rappi.com.br/api/rocket/v2/guest' \
-X 'POST' \
-H 'authority: services.rappi.com.br' \
-H 'accept: */*' \
-H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
-H 'content-length: 0' \
-H 'content-type: application/json' \
-H 'deviceid: aa86021c-a01c-4238-8703-debf4ab2985f' \
-H 'origin: https://www.rappi.com.br' \
-H 'referer: https://www.rappi.com.br/' \
-H 'sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="105", "Not)A;Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="105"' \
-H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
-H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"' \
-H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
-H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
-H 'sec-fetch-site: same-site' \
-H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
-H 'x-guest-api-key: kPFcVarmnF/dKTjdVf/FI263I3otKDy9ySvqRXteTx4jzvTARe2xc1OfP4CovswsR4kW8Hgz5mwHSg8BvfsQUL7pISNJz92+gpMm16znHFnl3aJGnKe1jGum4q6lRltwpBXfYSMrpc2YMCqopCIsMWYBJTdpub75sj0YL7NIOuQjURTWbmWwfwSNpEaRVkrKujNEYfM3sXWSsQpGooqCvtWW1Sbgzm4tB3jiljglchAunBdtLy8WstIufJgPzUSmNU/AlNfVCH94Zh5AX0rfftganulDlRH3Ch5/QyXQwYVMDWMXjBpdbIfMTxjXZxgmqo4MUVwsc32SMACQyOEDqg==' \
--compressed
```

Response:

```
{"access_token":"ft.gAAAAABjK3YB2MlWichQW2SuqOrudIcwNW-4-Ykb_0AwzDLR7tgrUzAPS7UW_Hf8FmC1BDITjW4pT6mWmwYaR7WBFtqlljjGSK770EqRiySfNBgEvCfD-EHFpBpGo3_7_wB76wwW-ohgUjN1zPBxSE7UowKHzWzf5aLIyAENYuX8vqNVGavJnIV33QKHFzIYT_XpJFWgu6LK1ZMGPna0PLyemmBx-bYQTSvEv3TUF_SQlV1SgGVmNIfKkS8d44Hc0IijtBQbjKHEadsfOE0x5gOeKtPQA8HURDDuVwQXMpH8cEPGDWoMi8mhGdBJ_pHkk7UtBfml141kH3QXsEY4FoJIc6T8is6AraNjRwAw_EeYs3ElxGG9bEA=","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":604800,"refresh_token":"ft.gAAAAABjK3YBpmtK_ox1r8DwkT8uO6HQVujT1XdPbDvJSXPOCb8ATfKM8Vr17Xe5so8yojA_uSpSIO1rUryKOccrJIu91M0piQ977haGi4dv__nmDUxYUf3_74waTkiJExVMjs72eRVsldEYmznZYjMRrmW-LkBee-S5s0zxtnrhkPme70LSiNYQ_HgqtEduCSLILwegmwn60WfWht3NUS4eJ_n7dTw2lDo_cAl6H_UtLTdEYu7AMf1sWA7TDAusiuON6FWENlPozl9Q3FTmOw27D6B8gGIhj5sV7unaqMGpxdIQXvrLi5LxYdL6L9kteK4p93u_roUw4Q1OscMgp6r1zGkVg0sfyI7EjIoQTC9_5RT1wiZ46Aw=","first_login":false}
```

Comment: Oh I forgot to update, I had solved it. But I'll accept your answer, because you're right, that's the way to get it, thanks anyway =]

Answer (score 0):

Normally the bearer token would be set in response you logging into the site, then returned by the server to the client, then sent by the client to the server on subsequent requests.

Are you performing a login?

Comment: No, I don't need to perform a login. I tried to get from the website, which is not the endpoint: 'https://www.rappi.com.br/lojas/900520986-makro-atacadista-nc/mercearia' but the results were the same..

Comment: It looks like it might be generated by a javascript function in the file https://www.rappi.com.br/static-cpgs/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app-ca9781e154e07014.js on line 1324.

Comment: Any tips to extract this data?

Comment: There's no data to extract. You would have to either run the javascript or (probably easier) reimplement the function in python.